# Dovecot: Corrupted Mbox index cache file

Tags: email, dovecot

I received following error message in `/var/mail/mail.err`:

```
Jun 14 00:03:42 max dovecot: IMAP(bernhard): 
Corrupted index cache file /home/bernhard/Mail/.indexes/.imap/INBOX/dovecot.index.cache: 
Broken virtual size for mail UID 5618
```

What is the preferred way to restore the index?

Comment: What version of Dovecot are you using? http://dovecot.2317879.n4.nabble.com/dovecot-index-errors-since-2-1-12-td39330.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to this thread titled: [IMAP Dovecot Error - Corrupted index cache 10.6.4](https://discussions.apple.com/message/12678432#12678432) it sounds like you just need to do the following:

> #### Scribit
>
> *Re: IMAP Dovecot Error - Corrupted index cache 10.6.4*
>
> *Nov 30, 2010 11:10 AM (in response to Scribit)*
>
> I am not sure if this is the best procedure and there may be unintended consequences, but this is what I did to resolve the issue.
>
> I stopped the mail service.
>
> From a shell, I navigated to each directory where an issue was reported.
>
> In these directories, I renamed the following files, prepending them with "old."
>
> ```
>    dovecot.index
>    dovecot.index.cache
>    dovecot.index.log
> ```
>
> EXAMPLE: `mv dovecot.index old.dovecot.index`
>
> I then restarted the mail service. These 3 files were recreated for each IMAP folder on client access.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is sufficient to delete the  affected files and restart dovecot. It creates new index files after start..

Comment: Given that [dovecot provides a tool to (re)build the index](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Index), shouldn’t `doveadm index -u <username> INBOX` do the trick?

Comment: @dessert I'd expect `doveadm index` to do exactly that but it seems it only adds unindexed emails to the index instead of completely rebuilding it.

Answer (score 3):

I find the easiest way to restore the index files is this.

Stop Dovecot

```
sudo systemctl stop dovecot
```

Rename, or delete, the entire .imap folder for any affected users (I prefer delete, but the cautious may feel otherwise)

```
sudo rm -R /home/bernhard/Mail/.indexes/.imap/
```

Start Dovecot

```
sudo systemctl start dovecot
```

When the mailbox is checked, Dovecot will simply recreate the indexes as if it were a new mailbox that it didn't see before, without missing a beat.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, deleting `dovecot.index` does not work, because some damaged email files corrupted dovecot.index again.

Example:

`Error: Corrupted record in index cache file /home/user/mail/domain/username/.INBOX/dovecot.index.cache: UID 1227: Broken virtual size in mailbox INBOX: read(/home/user/mail/domain/username/.INBOX/cur/1600772501.M603394P22807.paxaa.host.com,S=9099624,W=9217854:2,S): FETCH BODY[] got too little data: 2846393 vs 9217854`

Finally helped remove emails / restore from email backups that corrupted dovecot.index